# React Native: How to get shared albums in IOS?

Tags: react-native

I am using expo media library to get all the albums and photos but I can't find a way to get shared albums.

I tried:

> await MediaLibrary.getAlbumsAsync({ includeSmartAlbums: true })

But that returned smartAlbums and not cloud shared albums. Is there any way to do it using expo media library or any other library?

Comment: You can use the MediaLibrary module in React Native to get all the albums and photos. However, it does not provide a way to get shared albums.

You can try using the react-native-photo-library module instead. It provides a way to retrieve shared albums.

You can also use the react-native-image-picker module to select an image from any album.

Comment: let album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync("albumName");
let assets = await MediaLibrary.getAssetsAsync({album: album.id});

Comment: Can you paste the link for the library? Is it this one https://github.com/trabricks-react/react-native-photo-library?